# Is there a way to use more than 1 variable length arguments (*args) in a Python function?

Tags: python, args

I would like to create a function that uses two variable length arguments. For example:

```
def my_func(*args1, *args2):
    for i in args1:
        do stuff
    for j in args2:
        do stuff
```

Is there a way in Python to use more than one `*args`? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: So what is `args2` in `my_func(x,y,z)`?

Comment: What's your use case for this? It sounds to me like you should be defining two separate functions, if you need to do two different things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, as there is no way to decide whether

```
my_func(a, b)
```

means

```
args = [], args2 = [a,b] # or ..
args = [a], args2 = [b]  # or ..
args = [a,b], args2 = []
```

Instead, simply let the function take two lists as arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You should use lists. That way, it's obvious which item goes in which argument:

```
def my_func(args1, args2):
    for a in args1:
        print a
    for b in args2:
        print b

my_func([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array (or whatever Python's name for an array is) for each argument.  Otherwise, there's no way for Python to know where to split each set of variable length arguments.

Comment: Python also has arrays (for fast SIMD operations), but you most likely mean a *list*. Unlike an array, a list can be extended or shrunk.

Comment: Yup :).  Sounds like I mean a list.  Been a long, long time since I've written anything in Python.  (I really should have been more specific with 'array' since that implies static size....  Although really something of static length would be fine as long as it carried the length of itself with it)

Comment: Something of static length whose elements can be anything? That's a tuple ;) Luckily, the function just iterates over the argument, so anything *iterable* will work: lists, tuples, and arrays.

Answer (score 0):

How would you like to call the function? why not use two arrys or dicts?

Answer (score 0):

No that doesn't even make sense. What would determine what goes in the first list and what goes in the second? You can pass keyword arguments as well, though (in case you didn't know already):

```
def func(*args **kwargs):
    pass
```

What exactly is it that you are trying to accomplish?